# One line of code, several (related?) errors

Tags: fortran, gfortran

For reference: I am using gfortran version 6.3.0, running Windows 10. I have also attempted this on a different box, running Linux Mint and gfortran version 5.4.0, with the same results. The code itself is housed in .f files (not .f90 etc)

The problem: I am currently working with some old code which was provided by a collaborator. However, compilation fails at this line:

```
      open( LUNIO, file='Myfile', 
     $     status='replace' )
```

(This is the appearance of the line as provided by my collaborator.) Compiling this code gives three errors:

```
main.f:687:19:

      $     status='replace' )
                   1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
main.f:687:6:

      $     status='replace' )
      1
Error: Bad continuation line at (1)
main.f:687:6:

      $     status='replace' )
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

I've done a bit of research on the puzzle, and tried a few modifications, with no success. Adding an additional space before $ leaves me with:

```
main.f:686:24:

       open( LUNIO, file='myFile',
                        1
Error: Invalid value for FILE specification at (1)
main.f:687:7:

       $     status='replace' )
       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

The closest I've come is removing the line break entirely, converting the code to read

```
      open( LUNIO, file='Myfile', status='replace' )
```

This fix removes the invalid character error, but I am still suck with error:

```
main.f:686:24:

       open( LUNIO, file='MyFile', status='replace' )
                        1
Error: Invalid value for FILE specification at (1)
```

(It also fouls up my python wrapper, but that's not the worst thing in the world.)

Any ideas? I am not well versed in Fortran; I just change variables and run code other people write. This particular code was working for me last June, and as far as I know I haven't changed anything since then.

Comment: Modified the post to address your comments, thank you. Exact error messages posted. I did change the very long actual string name/address of the file to "MyFile" for neatness. "MyFile" is in standard Windows file structure form, 7 directories deep. I also added four spaces (for code block formatting) to the code blocks. It should appear exactly how it is for me, now.

Comment: "I did change the very long actual string name". The error lies there. You need to post the actual code.

Comment: Yes, if the actual file name takes you beyond column 72 your program is broken.

Comment: Note that the check is rather easy. Replace the "7 directories deep" path by just the file name. Move the executable to the same location as the file and execute the code from that location.

Comment: Thanks for the input; this is probably the root of the problem. A followup question: Will OPEN look in the correct place if the path is, say, '../Directory/Filename', like I might use with a cd command to change several directories at once?

Comment: Okay: I tried the fix suggested by Pierre and the problem persists. The filename itself is quite long. I shortened it as much as I could without sacrificing important information and reduced the length of the line of code to 70 characters, but it still fails to execute with errors: Syntax error at the comma at the end of the line containing OPEN, and invalid character in the status='replace' line.

Comment: how about a `&` at the end of the line with open as in 
`open( LUNIO, file='Myfile', &` 
`status='replace' )`
as a line break